# Prevent typeahead from specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a common country list for all users.But I want to prevent home country of each user from their typeahead.
This is my javascript function.

```
  $(function () {
        $('#country_field.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
              name: 'countries',
              source: countries_ta,
              display: 'name',
              limit: 6,
              templates: {
                  suggestion: suggestions_html,
                  pending: pending_html,
                  notFound: notFound_html
              }
        });

        $("#country_field").keyup(function (e) {
            $("#fg_country_wizard").removeClass("has-error");
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                var countryName = $(this).val();
                appendCountry(countryName);
                $('#country_field.typeahead').typeahead('close');
                $(this).val("")
            }
        });

    });
```

I can get country that should prevent to the variable as follows.

```
var homeCountryDid = $('#hid_HomeCountryDid').val();
```

Comment: please include more detail and example code, ideally via a fiddle (with dummy data if needed). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Read the docs, cancel selection. What's the problem?